# Is there a Mac OS X equivalent of Windows' named pipe

Tags: c++, macos, ffmpeg, named-pipes, firemonkey

In windows I use named pipes to interface to a console program (ffmpeg). Thought I had a try rewriting this for the Mac, but I cannot find named pipe support in either FireMonkey or even native OS X code. Does it exist at all?

Comment: Code hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961797/reading-from-named-pipes-in-linux-vs-os-x

Comment: Named pipes are made using `mkfifo`. Unix domain sockets are the alternative: they're bidirectional, so strictly more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the system pipes use `lsof | grep PIPE`.